# SQL sum values for each ID

Tags: sql, sum

I have a dataset about trains, it's including a table for the customers information which is a number representing an age group and the amount of travellers for that age group.

The ID represents a location which has multiple departure times, which has multiple age groups.

The data looks something like this

| StationID | Time of Departure | TravellerID | Amount of travellers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:13 | 4001 | 30 |
| 1 | 12:13 | 4002 | 15 |
| 1 | 19:45 | 4001 | 10 |
| 1 | 19:45 | 4002 | 20 |

I want to sum the amount of travellers for each departure
I tried to code it this way:

```
SELECT StationID,[Time of Departure], sum(Amount)
FROM Train_Stations AS TS

INNER JOIN DepartureData AS DD
ON DD.FK_StationID = TS.PK_StationID
INNER JOIN CustomerInfo AS CI
ON CI.FK_StationID = TS.PK_StationID

GROUP BY StationID, [Time of Departure]
```

The result is like this:

| StationID | Time of Departure | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:13 | 75 |
| 1 | 12:13 | 75 |
| 1 | 19:45 | 75 |
| 1 | 19:45 | 75 |

But I want it like this:

| StationID | Time of Departure | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:13 | 45 |
| 1 | 19:45 | 30 |

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns (at least when several tables are involved.) Like `TS.PK_StationID` instead of just `Amount`. (We don't know which table Amount belongs to.)

Comment: Good tip, I try to pay attention to this

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you do something different.Based on your data query is correct

```
 WITH CTE(StationID,DEPARTURE_TIME,TRAVELLERID,AMOUNT_OF_TRAVELLERS) AS
 (
   SELECT 1,CAST('12:13'AS TIME),4001,30 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,CAST('12:13'AS TIME),4002,15 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,CAST('19:45'AS TIME),4001,10 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,CAST('19:45'AS TIME),4002,20  
 ) 
 SELECT C.StationID,C.DEPARTURE_TIME,SUM(AMOUNT_OF_TRAVELLERS)TOTAL_TRAVELLERS
 FROM CTE AS C
 GROUP BY C.StationID,C.DEPARTURE_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the column as `DD.StationID`. It will return as an expected result.

```
SELECT DD.StationID,DD.[Time of Departure], sum(DD.Amount)
FROM Train_Stations AS TS

INNER JOIN DepartureData AS DD
ON DD.FK_StationID = TS.PK_StationID
INNER JOIN CustomerInfo AS CI
ON CI.FK_StationID = TS.PK_StationID

GROUP BY DD.StationID, DD.[Time of Departure]
```